# Flutter Google Maps: Avoiding infinite loop when updating camera position in

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm working on a Flutter app that uses the Google Maps Flutter plugin. I have a method fetchAndSetNearestLocation() that fetches the nearest location to the center of the currently visible map region and updates the map to focus on that location. I'm trying to call this method when the user stops dragging the map.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
GoogleMap(
  // other properties...
  onCameraIdle: () {
    mapBeingDragged.value = false;
    fetchAndSetNearestLocation();
  },
  // other properties...
),
```

The problem is that fetchAndSetNearestLocation() itself triggers a camera movement by calling animateCamera(), which in turn triggers the onCameraIdle callback, creating an infinite loop.

I tried introducing a boolean flag to check whether the camera should move or not, but it didn't work. Here's what I tried:

```
bool shouldFetchAndSetLocation = false;

// ...

GoogleMap(
  // other properties...
  onCameraMoveStarted: () {
    mapBeingDragged.value = true;
    shouldFetchAndSetLocation = true;
  },
  onCameraIdle: () async {
    mapBeingDragged.value = false;
    if (shouldFetchAndSetLocation) {
      shouldFetchAndSetLocation = false;
      await fetchAndSetNearestLocation();
    }
  },
  // other properties...
),
```

How can I correctly call fetchAndSetNearestLocation() when the user stops dragging the map, without causing an infinite loop? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetNearestLocation() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    final LatLngBounds visibleRegion = await controller.getVisibleRegion();

    final LatLng center = LatLng(
      (visibleRegion.northeast.latitude + visibleRegion.southwest.latitude) / 2,
      (visibleRegion.northeast.longitude + visibleRegion.southwest.longitude) /
          2,
    );

    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url here)
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final points = data['routes'][0]['overview_polyline']['points'];

      final result = PolylinePoints().decodePolyline(points);
      final nearestLocation = result.first;

      // change map center
      controller.animateCamera(
        CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
          LatLng(nearestLocation.latitude, nearestLocation.longitude),
        ),
      );
      setState(() {
        _mapChosenLocation =
            LatLng(nearestLocation.latitude, nearestLocation.longitude);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use debounce inside onCameraMoveStarted() and you can ignore the onCameraIdle(). For more about debounce: https://pub.dev/packages/easy_debounce